# Node.js how to get path between host and a filename?

Tags: node.js

I am struggling with this one.. I want to get the path between hostname and filename:

http://host.com/this/is/what/i/want/file.jpg

Method should return "this/is/what/i/want".

I was looking at the URL module but can't find the right property.

```
url.parse(host).pathname
```

returns the whole path but **with** the filename :(.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do substring with the full pathname info you have

```
var pathname = url.parse(host).pathname;
pathname = pathnam.substring(0,pathname.lastIndexOf("/"));
```

Answer (score 8):

This requires the [`path`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.11/api/path.html) and [`url`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.11/api/url.html) built-in node modules.

```
var path = require("path"),
    url = require("url"),
    myUrl = "http://host.com/this/is/what/i/want/file.jpg",
    dir = path.dirname(url.parse(myUrl).pathname);

console.log(dir); // -> /this/is/what/i/want
```